# Is electric voltage fade in and fade out?

Tags: voltage, amperage, power-flow-analysis

Consider theres a LED through switch with power from DC power supply. It will on when switch is close and off when switch is open.

From closed switch we open the switch, so the LED will turned off. But was LED instantly turned off? Or theres time it's still ON after switch closed?
And the question is vice versa when we close the switch from the opened switch.

If LED not instantly,
Is it happen because capacitor from power supply? If true, Consider the power supply doesnt have capacitor at all like battery AA 1.5v will it be same?

Who the fade in/out? Current or voltage or both?

Answer (score 1):

Everything has capacitance so you cannot instantly turn an LED (or anything) on or off.  There is always some time required to discharge that capacitance.  For a normal (non-white) LED, turning on/off takes tens or hundreds of nanoseconds during which time the brightness gradually increases or decreases towards the final value.

In the case of a white LED, the phosphor coating remains excited for microseconds after the diode stops emitting.  During this time even though the LED is off, the phosphor continues to glow.

Comment: So it has delay and fade in/out too when i close/open the switch?

Comment: Im still confused, so it's delay or fade in/fade out?

Comment: So the timeline when i close the switch (make LED on) are, first electric need time for example 200nano second to touch/reach LED, time needed depends on wire (cmiiw). second, electric trying to charging LED which that makes brightness fade in effect, third, finally the LED fully charged which it's constant brightness?  Correct me if im wrong about my conclusion